# Problemas ao executar função do Mysql usando o FireDAC do Delphi 10.1

Tags: mysql, delphi, funções, firedac

Em um banco MySql tenho uma função(Não é procedure) totalmente funcional, consigo acessar normalmente dentro do heidisql.

No Delphi, faço o seguinte

```
function ExecutarFuncaoSQL(sFuncao: string; aParams: array of Variant; conBanco: TFDConnection): Variant;
begin
   with TFDCustomStoredProc.Create(nil) do
   try
      Connection := conBanco;
      Result := ExecFunc(sFuncao, aParams);
   finally
      Free;
   end;
end;
```

Isso está de acordo com o que há no site do Delphi ->[Documentação do Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomStoredProc.ExecFunc)

Porém, quando tento executar recebo o seguinte erro

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project InterfaceAPI.exe raised exception class EMySQLNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] PROCEDURE gravarconsulta does not exist'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

Estou usando o componente de maneira errada? Obs: quero evitar fazer direto por select

Edit[1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomStoredProc.ExecFunc):
Quando executo essa function, ela roda normalmente no BD(faz Inserts e select), porém ainda tenho problemas relacionados a este erro retornado. Fiz novos testes usando outro componente, mas nada feito.

```
with TFDStoredProc.Create(nil) do
```

Comment: Bruno, esse `gravarconsulta` que ele está gritando no output, ele está sendo chamado de algum lugar?

Comment: Eu chamo a  [function ExecutarFuncaoSQL] assim -> ExecutarFuncaoSQL('gravarconsulta ', [param1, param2 .....])